# The Fubini-Study form on the complex projective space can be obtained from the Symplectic reduction

Tags: differential-geometry, complex-geometry, symplectic-geometry

For a complex complex plane $\mathbb{CP}^{n}$, there is a natural Kähler form
$$\omega=\partial\overline{\partial}\log\sum_{i=0}^{n}z_i\overline{z_i}$$
Which is so called the Fubini-Study form, where $\partial$ and $\overline{\partial}$ are the Dolbeault operators.

If we let $\mathbb{C}^{n+1}$ endowed with a Hamiltonian $S^1$-action, by
$$t(z_0,...,z_n)\mapsto (t.z_0,...,t.z_n)$$
Then it is a Hamiltonian action with the moment map
$$\mu(z_0,...,z_n)=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=0}^n|z_i|^2$$
Then for any positive $a>0$ is a regular value of $\mu$, so there is a reduced Symplectic form $\sigma$ on the quotient space $\mu^{-1}(a)/S^1\cong \mathbb{CP}^n$.

My question is, Do these two forms coincide? If so, how to compute it? I have no ideas how to do the computation.

Comment: Yes, they coincide (up to possibly rescaling on of them by a constant)

Comment: @NickL But how to compute that?